# Render string input of ng-content directly as HTML

Tags: html, angular, innerhtml, ng-content

Is it possible for a component to receive content passed to it between opening and closing tags and assign the input directly to `innerHTML` inside the receiving template?

I have a `string` input like this:

```js
public content: string =
  '<div class="row">' +
  '  <div class="col">' +
  '    <h1>Friendly greetings!</h1>' +
  '    <p>' +
  '      This is my homepage..' +
  '    </p>' +
  '  </div>' +
  '</div>';
```

And put it in my component like this:

```html
<app-content>{{ content }}</app-content>
```

Inside `app-content` I can use `ng-content` in the template to project the input content. Since the input is a `string` I only get to see a `string`, the HTML elements it describes are not rendered.

I tried to inject the `ElementRef` and access the text node via `this.elementRef.nativeElement.textContent`, but the content must have been rendered first to access it that way.

Of course, I could hide the content `ng-content` produces like this:

```html
<div style="display: none">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

And then get the `textContent` in a variable (e.g. `content`) and set it like this:

```html
<div [outerHTML]="content"></div>
```

But that seems hacky to me.

StackBlitz project: [get-input-of-ng-content-directly](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-input-of-ng-content-directly)

Am I missing something?

I want to do something like this in the template: `<div [outerHTML]="incoming ng-content stuff"></div>`

Or at least inject the content in the components constructor and set it to a variable, but without rendering the content first just to hide it.

Comment: I think that's possible, but... why don't you pass the string (that's coming from the server, I guess) to an `@Input()` in `app-content`?

Comment: And you don't want to do `<app-content><div [outerHTML]="content"></div></app-content>` in the parent component?

Comment: I am specifically interested in this use-case, because I want to have a lean element usage. No extra attributes, no helper constructs, just the content between the tags in and then access to it directly.. without that hack described above.

It does not seem possible as I imagine it, but it definitely should be.

Comment: @julianobrasil Can you please elaborate how that might be possible?

Comment: Johannes, it's something in the same direction as @tlm's answer below. In addition to that answer, I'd just bypass some of angular's sanitizers or you won't be able to insert styles, classes, etc, along with the incoming HTML.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I added a [StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-input-of-ng-content-directly). Goal is to provide content like this: `<app-content>{{ content }}</app-content>` and get it without having to render it first.

Comment: I am wondering why you absolutely want to use interpolation instead of doing it like [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-input-of-ng-content-directly-agtcey?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), or using @tlm's first suggestion.

Comment: I created a feature request for this: [Get direct access to ng-content input](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/40293)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you have two options:

1.)  `@Input()` field that receives your `content` above and then renders the `content` as `innerHTML` like you mentioned.  So something like

`<app-content [content]="content"></app-content>`

And then you can render you `content` `Input` like you have above with the `<div [innerHTML]=...`

2.) Or you can use `<ng-content>` inside of your `<app-content>` HTML file and then just do something like this:

```
<app-content>
  <div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
</app-content>
```

But this second option probably assumes `<app-content>` is not the root element from which your Angular app is boostrapped.

Comment: So you think accessing the incoming content between the tags directly is not an option?

Comment: @Johannes If I'm understanding what you want to do correctly, maybe you could try something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tj4yeu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts 

I used `Renderer2` to `setProperty` on the components `ElementRef` based on the string attribute you mentioned above.  If that's what you're thinking, I could see how you might also make that a directive to make it reusable across components (and prevent DI for each one).

Comment: Please have a look at my [StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-input-of-ng-content-directly). Goal is to provide the incoming content like this: `<app-content>{{ content }}</app-content>` and get it without rendering it hidden.